# Container View animations not working properly when changing out a background image

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uicontainerview

I have 3 Views in IB. View One(1) has a view and an UIImage that I am using as the background for this ViewController. View Two(2)(Details View) and View Three(3)(Options View) are Container Views, both placed on top of each other. I have a button in View 2 that animations View 2 off to the left and moves View 3 on from the right. And I am able to go back from View 3 moving off to the right and bringing View 2 back on from the left.

Here is what my Document Outline looks like:
[image]

The White BG, is just a background under the title bar, just in case anyone is wondering.

Here is the code that I am using to do those animations:

```
func showOptions(){
    println("show options")

    optionsView.center.x = self.view.bounds.width + self.view.bounds.width / 2
    optionsView.hidden = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        self.blurView.alpha = 1

        // slide containers around
        // println(self.view.bounds.width)

        self.detailsView.center.x = -self.view.bounds.width * 2
        self.optionsView.center.x = self.view.bounds.width / 2
    })
}
func showDetails(){
    println("show detials")

     optionsView.center.x = self.view.bounds.width / 2

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        self.blurView.alpha = 0

        // slide containers around
        // println(self.view.bounds.width)

        self.detailsView.center.x = self.view.bounds.width / 2
        println("\(self.optionsView.center.x) this is center X value 1")

        self.optionsView.center.x = self.view.bounds.width * 2
        println("\(self.optionsView.center.x) this is center X value 2")

    }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            println("\(self.optionsView.center.x) this is center X value 3")
    })
}
```

Those that are curious as to what I get back from the print statements

When I don't try to change out the background photo and things work like this should I get this:

- 160.0 this is center X value 1
- 640.0 this is center X value 2
- 640.0 this is center X value 3

When I change out the photo I get these values:

- 160.0 this is center X value 1
- 640.0 this is center X value 2
- 160.0 this is center X value 3

What doesn't work is when I try to change out the image of the background view for this view controller.

```
let par3 = UIImage(named: "par3.png")
backgroundImage.image = par3
   // println("par three")
    showDetails()
```

When I change out the background photo, both View 2 and View 3 animate onto the screen from the left. I'm just not sure why. Does it have something to do with the width of the View Controller being modified when I switch out the background photo?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels like you are only half embracing Auto Layout. You're using it to lay out your views initially, but then you're not using it when you're animating the views. You're modifying the center x position, which is the old way of animating. It's kind of working, but then I think everything is getting reset to your initial constraints when you swap out the background image, since that causes a call to `layoutIfNeeded()` under the hood, which uses the constraints to position everything back how it was initially.

Instead of modifying the center x position of the views you need to change your approach to modify the constraints instead. This will mean that even when you swap out the image your constraints will still be accurate and everything should work as expected. This requires setting up your constraints in a particular way, which I'll try and demonstrate.

First I have set up a parent view controller with a couple of child view controllers. Each of the children have a button that calls a delegate method back in the parent.

My storyboard looks like this:

[image: storyboard setup]

Here's what the inspector looks like:

[image: storyboard inspector]

A few points about the storyboard setup:

- I have a main container view that is a subview of the parent view. This main container view has clipSubviews set to YES, so that when we move views to the left and right they don't show up outside the bounds of the main container.
- Both the options and detail container views have constraints set to match the width and height of the main container view.
- The left side of the detail container view is set to butt up right against the right side of the options container view, i.e. [options][detail]. They are not directly on top of each other.
- The detail container view has a constraint so that it's top edge lines up with the top edge of the options container view.
- The options container view is set up with constraints to line up with the top left of the main container view. This combined with the previous 2 bullets means that initially the detail container view is off the screen to the right. I have a reference in the parent view controller to the constraint that lines up the left side of the options container view with the left side of the mainContainerView (the one that is selected in the above screenshot), and that's what I use to animate everything.

This is what the parent class looks like:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, OptionsViewControllerDelegate, DetailViewControllerDelegate {

    struct Constants {
        static let optionsEmbedSegue = "optionsEmbedSegue"
        static let detailEmbedSegue = "detailEmbedSegue"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mainContainerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var optionsLeadingSpaceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == Constants.optionsEmbedSegue {
            let childViewController = segue.destinationViewController as OptionsViewController
            childViewController.delegate = self
        } else if segue.identifier == Constants.detailEmbedSegue {
            let childViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            childViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func optionsViewControllerDidSelectToShowDetail(optionsViewController: OptionsViewController) {
        animateOptionsToNewXPosition(-CGRectGetWidth(mainContainerView.bounds))
    }

    func detailViewControllerDidSelectToGoBack(detailViewController: DetailViewController) {
        animateOptionsToNewXPosition(0)
    }

    func animateOptionsToNewXPosition(xPosition: CGFloat) {
        optionsLeadingSpaceConstraint.constant = xPosition

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.mainContainerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the `optionsViewControllerDidSelectToShowDetail` method, you'll see the line `animateOptionsToNewXPosition(-CGRectGetWidth(mainContainerView.bounds))`. This is moving the options view controller off to the left in the amount of the width of the main container view. This means that it will disappear off to the left of the screen, and because of all the other constraints, it will drag the detail view controller with it, revealing the detail view controller in the `mainContainerView`. The opposite happens in the `detailViewControllerDidSelectToGoBack` method, simply setting the constant in that constraint back to 0, which brings the options view controller back, and pushes the detailViewController off to the right.

I hope that helps.